# Are feature module's providers visible everywhere?

Tags: angular

[Angular document](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#why-is-a-service-provided-in-a-feature-module-visible-everywhere) says providers that are declared at module level are visible to the entire application:

> Providers listed in the @NgModule.providers of a bootstrapped module have application scope. Adding a service provider to @NgModule.providers effectively publishes the service to the entire application.

So, this means that services from a module(`AAAModule`) can be injected into another one(`BBBModule`). But, other [Angular document](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#ngmodule-level-injectors) says we can limit the scope of the provider to specific module by declaring the provider at `@NgModule`:

> You can configure a provider at the module level using the providedIn metadata option for a non-root NgModule, in order to limit the scope of the provider to that module.

In the same way, [another document](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#component-level-injectors) says we can limit the provider's scope to specific component:

> Individual components within an NgModule have their own injectors. You can limit the scope of a provider to a component and its children by configuring the provider at the component level using the @Component metadata.

So, What's the fact? If i declare a provider at module level, is it visible to the entire application or the module? The "scope" is meaning only "lifetime" of provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the missing piece in your understanding that is causing your confusion is Angular's [lazy loading feature](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules). Modules that are loaded lazily will have their own injectors (but inherits from the root injector). Therefore providers listed in modules that are loaded lazily will be scoped to that module and will only live for as long as the route that maps to that module.

When modules are imported into other modules (not loaded lazily), then all the providers listed in those modules are merged into the same injector. Those providers will live for the entire application lifetime.

Providers listed in components will only live as long as that component. For example, consider a component that lists a provider and is within an `*ngIf` that can be toggled. When the component gets created, that's when the provider is created as well. When the component is destroyed, so is the provider. The provider is only accessible in that component and any component/directive, and their providers that they list, that are descendants in the DOM tree.

Consider the following examples:

- Module A is imported into AppModule

  - Providers listed in Module A reside in the root injector. That means that the provider is available across the whole app and lives for the entire life of the app.
- Module B is loaded lazily

  - A child injector is created. Providers listed in Module B or the providers that are listed in any module that is imported into Module B will reside in that new injector.

So far I have only discussed providers that are listed in the module files. Then comes the more recent convention (as of Angular 6) of using [`providedIn` in the `@Injectable` decorator](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#providing-a-singleton-service). I recommend you take a look at [this article](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/total-guide-to-angular-6-dependency-injection-providedin-vs-providers-85b7a347b59f). While the article talks about the old way of listing providers in modules vs the new way of using `providedIn`, I think it may help you understand the scope in which providers are available as well.

Comment: So, this("You can configure a provider at the module level using the providedIn metadata option for a non-root NgModule, in order to limit the scope of the provider to that module.") will only be applied when using lazy loading?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to find a more helpful reference :) Modules do not have their own injector except if a module is loaded lazily. I will try to expand my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

> Providers listed in the @NgModule.providers of a bootstrapped module have application scope. Adding a service provider to @NgModule.providers effectively publishes the service to the entire application.

If you  declare the providers in the root module decorator `providers` array, then yes the scope is the entire application. It is associated with the root injector making the same singleton instance available across the application.If a provider is declared in a feature module then it won't be available unless that module is imported. But if declared in ***root module*** it is available everywhere.

> You can configure a provider at the module level using the providedIn metadata option for a non-root NgModule, in order to limit the scope of the provider to that module.

If you use the `@Injectable` and mention the provider's scope in the `providedIn` property then only those modules which are importing the module where the service is declared is going to get that instance. This enables tree-shaking, which essentially means to exclude the provider code from the final bundle if it is not used in the application.

For lazy loaded modules, another child of the root injector gets created which copies every thing from the root injector plus the providers declared in the lazy modules. In the context of lazy loaded components the providers are injected from this child injector instead of from the root injector.

> Individual components within an NgModule have their own injectors. You
>   can limit the scope of a provider to a component and its children by
>   configuring the provider at the component level using the @Component
>   metadata.

In this case every component is going to get their own copy of the provider and which would be a different instance form the one configured in the root injector. Do this when you need a private copy of a provider which you don't want to share across components.